# Django design patterns - Forms for Create and Update a Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Suppose I want to create and update a model. What fields are displayed and the type of validation depends on the action (create or update). But they still share a lot of the same validation and functality. Is there a clean way to have a ModelForm handle this (besides just if instance exists everywhere) or should I just create two different model forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities spring to mind. You could set an attribute in the form's `__init__` method, either based on a parameter you explicitly pass in, or based on whether `self.instance` exists and has a non-None pk:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # either:
        self.edit = kwargs.pop('edit', False)
        # or:
        self.edit = hasattr(self, instance) and self.instance.pk is not None
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # now modify self.fields dependent on the value of self.edit
```

The other option is to subclass your modelform - keep the joint functionality in the base class, then the specific create or update functionality in the subclasses.

Comment: cool, that's what I was thinking too. Was wondering if there was some better way to do it, but this looks good to me.